# Testing out different scenarios in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I created a spreadsheet that calculates salaries for employees using a few different models of growth (different base, different rate of increase per year) . It takes a date and calculates monthly salaries for all employees.

I would like to be able to see differences over time. Right now I can do it by manually changing the date and copying the result into a separate sheet, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do it automatically, for example iterate over months and store the results somewhere.

[spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aWZIFo9c3SPVnKbzAXnuTrG3LAqFSRslogwCjYIb6uY/edit?usp=sharing)

Basically I would like to be able to iterate over different values in cell D1 and store the values of different cells such as N2, R2 or basically any others in a separate sheet or file

Comment: this is too broad. share a copy of your sheet and state the specific issue with an example of the desired result

Comment: I updated the question @user0

Answer (score -2):

I found a way to do that by creating a simple python script using gspread

Comment: Hi kuleje, could you elaborate a bit?